# Shading an area between y axis points in a WPF Toolkit Line Chart

Tags: wpf, mvvm, c#-4.0, charts

I am using line chart in wpf. I have given min and max values along the y - axis with the interval of 50. I want to shade the intervals with color i.e. 0-50 blue color, 50-100 red color and so on. How to go about this in wpf line chart??

Kindly help?

Thank You..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple `AreaSeries` on the same `Chart`.  Here is a sample chart:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <PointCollection x:Key="sampleData1">
            <Point X="0" Y="20"/>
            <Point X="25" Y="30"/>
            <Point X="50" Y="25"/>
        </PointCollection>
        <PointCollection x:Key="sampleData2">
            <Point X="50" Y="25"/>
            <Point X="75" Y="40"/>
            <Point X="100" Y="35"/>
        </PointCollection>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <chartingToolkit:Chart Title="Colored Y Ranges">
        <chartingToolkit:AreaSeries
            Title="First Section"
            ItemsSource="{StaticResource sampleData1}"
            IndependentValuePath="X"
            DependentValuePath="Y">
        </chartingToolkit:AreaSeries>
        <chartingToolkit:AreaSeries
            Title="Second Section"
            ItemsSource="{StaticResource sampleData2}"
            IndependentValuePath="X"
            DependentValuePath="Y">
        </chartingToolkit:AreaSeries>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
</Grid>
```

which looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Will try and let you know.

Comment: Whenever I tried to use ur code as given by you. I am getting an error: "Object must be of type Double". Kindly suggest?

Comment: The example is just XAML-only; I've just tested creating brand new WPF3.5 and WPF4 applications, adding the DataVisualization.Toolkit reference, adding the System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting namespace, and pasting in the XAML and the graph you see even shows up in the designer.  Please try in a brand new project and then compare with your existing project if one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: Can we do the same for x axis? I want to show some threshhold line. Kindly suggest?